# How to get details from another table using comma operator in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables customer,category

category:

```
category_id    category_name     vendor_id 

      1             laptops       10

      2              bikes         10

      3              cars          10
```

customer:

```
user_name      password  assigned_categories vendor_id

    nag       12345          1,2,3          10
```

When I login with user_name and password ...I need to get all  category_id, category_name's from category.but am getting only  first category details like

```
 category_id=1,category_name=laptops
```

Comment: what are you talking about? totally confused.

Comment: Well, how do you expect anyone to help you, if you don't post anything about your actual code?

Comment: Post your code as well, what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your customer table does not abide by the [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) because you are storing multiple values in the `assigned_categories` attribute. If you would create a new table customer_assignments, it could all be easily done with basic `SQL` commands.

Here's how the new table `customer_assignments` would look:

> user_name (FK)
>
> category_id (FK)
>
> PRIMARY KEY(user_name, category_id)

[Many-to-Many relationships](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) should be handled like this, not by adding multiple values into one attribute.

You could then extract your required information with a query like:

```
SELECT category_id, category_name
FROM (category NATURAL JOIN customer_assignments) NATURAL JOIN customer
WHERE user_name = your_current_user_name
```

Comment: how to abide customer table by 1NF

Comment: Remove the assigned_categories attribute and create the table I mentioned above.

Comment: how to insert ,update multiple category_id's in customer_assignments table at once

Comment: You would use a foreign key with CASCADE ON UPDATE.

Comment: i dont know how to write queries by using CASDAE ON UPDATE...will u help me ..because u know my requirement

Comment: You would edit the customer_assignments table. You would add a foreign key from field customer_assignments.category_id to category.category_id. If you're using MySQL Workbench this is trivial. Otherwise, please Google the exact syntax for this. This basically tells MySQL to update the values in the customer_assignments table when the value changes in the category table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not changed your structure then below query will help you to get the your required result

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT SET @Test = assigned_categories FROM customer WHERE user_name  = 'nag'
IF LEN(@Test) > 0
BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #Temp(category_id VARCHAR(MAX))
        WHILE LEN(@Test) > 0
          BEGIN
          IF CHARINDEX(',',@Test) > 0
          BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(LEFT(@Test,CHARINDEX(',',@Test)-1))
            SET @Test = SUBSTRING(@Test,CHARINDEX(',',@Test) + 1,LEN(@Test))
          END
          ELSE 
          BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(@Test)  
            SET @Test = ''
              END
          END
        SELECT * FROM category INNER JOIN #Temp ON category.category_id = #Temp.category_id
END
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe using [SQL IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) may help, which allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

Comment: That will not work as it will still compare individual records with individual records and any number will be different from "1,2,3".